# Is there a standard convention for allocating namespaces?

Tags: namespaces

When ever I divide a program up into separate namespaces, I usually just end up with a situation where almost every class needs to reference almost every other namespace. Am I just doing it wrong? What are we trying to achieve with namespaces and how do you set out to achieve it?